# How to change font color and fontsize of FreeTextAnnotations (itext 7)?

Tags: pdf, annotations, itext, itext7

i create a `PdfFreeTextAnnotation` but the `setColor-Method` is only für the background of the Annotation.

How to set the actual `fontcolor`, `fontsize` and font?

```
Dim rec As iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle = ...

Dim anno As Annot.PdfFreeTextAnnotation = New 
Annot.PdfFreeTextAnnotation(rec, New PdfString(_annotation.Text))

anno.SetName(New PdfString(_annotation.Name))
anno.SetFlags(192)

anno.SetBorder(New iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfAnnotationBorder(0, 0, 0))

pdfDoc.GetPage(_annotation.PageNumber).AddAnnotation(anno)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeText annotations have `RC` key that allows setting a rich text string that shall be used to generate the appearance of the annotation. Basically you can use plain HTML as a rich text string, e.g. you can wrap some text in a `<span>` and set the text color in `style` attribute of that span, just as in HTML.

Here is the code in C# that does the trick:

```
anno.SetRichText(new PdfString("<span style=\"color:#10FF10;\">Hello world</span>"));
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much. I was thinking about using the SetRichText function, but the documentary was only talking about the popup text. But its working for the normal appearance anyway.